# Power Automate how to get the latest file in a folder?

Tags: power-automate

I found this site answering my query but the answer is for UiPath not Power automate. Is there a way to implement that code in Power Automate?

[Power Automate screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BLgY.png)

http://microsoftrpa.com/get-latest-file-in-folder/

```
GetFiles(folder_path,".xlsx",SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(Function(d) New FileInfo(d).CreationTime).Tolist(0)
```